# how to implement an admin approval system for posting blogs in pythondjango

Tags: python, django, view, admin

I am building a website where user come and login, after login user publish articles with admin approval . I do not know how to do it. I made a user authentication system where user can login. But i do not know how to make him post data with admin approval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Therefor you need a condition in your model to be able to query the approved objects (blog posts) to display.

A basic approach could look as follows:

Create a model to store the blog posts and its logic to the database

```
# models.py

class Blog_Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Register your model in the admin so you can approve them via django-admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Blog_Post

admin.site.register(Blog_Post)
```

Create a view to only fetch blog posts that have been approved by an admin

```
# views.py

def get_blog_post(request):

   # Only fetch the blog posts that are approved
   queryset = Blog_Post.objects.filter(is_approved=True)

   return render(request, 'your_html.html', {'queryset' : queryset})
```

Render the blog posts in your template

```
# your_html.html

{% for blog_post in queryset %}

<div>{{ blog_post.text }}</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sir now i clearly understand but how admin approved the posts?

Comment: You go to www.yoursite.com/admin, login and approve the blog post by using the model instance in the admin site

Answer (score 0):

That's a Good one. You can enable this with adding a new column to your database like `onapproval` Set it as an boolean variable like 0 or 1 either true or false. Then check for it. If it's true you can set the status as approved and if it is not set it as not approved. The same process will also takes place in admin panel too.